# Can I make a class which inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Form class always open in code view?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am working on Windows Form project. In which I need one class which inherit `System.Windows.Forms.Form`, I name it as `FormBase.cs` and inherit `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class. But in Solution Explorer `FormBase.cs` got view like Windows Form.. Now when I try to open file from Solution Explorer it open in Design Mode. Since it is simple `class` I expect it must open in Code View not in Design View. Why it happens? What should I do if I want `FormBase.cs` always open in Code View and regain its Class View in Solution Explorer?
`FormBase.cs` looks like :

```
public class FormBase : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    public virtual Dictionary<string, string> NonSaveableReasons()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> _nonSavebleReasons = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        //MaskedTextBox.MaskedTextBox and MaskedTextBox.MyCombo are Custom Components
        //which are of type TextBox and ComboBox respectively
        //having 2 more properties name as "IsMandatory" and "LabelName"

        foreach (MaskedTextBox.MaskedTextBox maskTextBox in this.Controls.OfType<MaskedTextBox.MaskedTextBox>())
        {
            if (maskTextBox.IsMandatory && string.IsNullOrEmpty(maskTextBox.Text) && !_nonSavebleReasons.ContainsKey(maskTextBox.Name))
                _nonSavebleReasons.Add(maskTextBox.Name, maskTextBox.LabelName + " is mandatory.");
        }

        foreach (MaskedTextBox.MyCombo myCombo in this.Controls.OfType<MaskedTextBox.MyCombo>())
        {
            if (myCombo.IsMandatory && string.IsNullOrEmpty(myCombo.Text) && !_nonSavebleReasons.ContainsKey(myCombo.Name))
            {
                if (!_nonSavebleReasons.ContainsKey(myCombo.Name))
                    _nonSavebleReasons.Add(myCombo.Name, myCombo.LabelName + " is mandatory.");
            }
        }

        return _nonSavebleReasons;
    }

    public string GetValidationStringMsg(Dictionary<string, string> nonSavableResons)
    {
        return nonSavableResons != null ? String.Join(Environment.NewLine, nonSavableResons.Select(a => a.Value).ToArray()) : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is because form is decorated with `DesignerAttribute`. righclick->ViewCode to open cs file

Comment: Maybe you want to try another kind of `IDE` which supports this feature, I guess this is stuck 4ever.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Can I do with `DesignerAttribute` so that `BaseForm.cs` gets open in Code View?

Comment: @KingKing I dont know such `IDE` which provide me better Programming support rather than Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you tried @jon's suggestion. righclick->OpenWith->CSharpEditor set as default

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes but now its applied for all normal Forms.. Means all Form now open in Code View.

Comment: You want VS to read your mind and guess that *this* form is not a form even though it looks exactly like form.  It's not smart enough for that.

Comment: So you expect VS to know that this specific form should not open in design view? the only way is to not inherit System.Windows.Forms.Form.

Comment: @HansPassant Why not..! There are n no of things are there which VS does and This is not too much big thing for it to rectify which is normal Form and which is not.

Comment: @NicolasTyler If it is not possible then at least VS should have some tools which handle this.

Comment: ... or an attribute which prevents the form from being opened in design mode. This behavior bugs me as well.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar I (and many others) don't really find any inconvenience with it. However you may hope this feature will be supported in next version of VS. Even the newest version 2012 may not support this.

Comment: @KingKing Me too..! But I am expecting answer for this question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designercategoryattribute.aspx) to prevent Visual Studio from opening one particular file in the designer. There are two ways you can apply this attribute.

### Option A

**Step 1.** Apply the attribute to `FormBase`, specifying `""` as the category:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")]
public class FormBase : System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

**Step 2.** Apply the attribute to every form deriving from `FormBase`, specifying `"Form"` as the category:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Form")]
public partial class MainForm : FormBase
```

Note that you **must** use the fully qualified type name of the attribute. This doesn't work:

```
// BAD CODE - DON'T USE
using System.ComponentModel;

[DesignerCategory("")]
public class FormBase : System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

### Option B

In FormBase.cs, **above** `FormBase`, add a dummy class and apply the attribute to it, specifying `""` as the category:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")]
internal class Unused
{
}

public class FormBase : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    // ...
}
```

With this approach, you don't need to apply the attribute to every form deriving from `FormBase`, at the cost of an unused class.

Comment: This works fine. And I find `[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")]` only required to add above class defination of `FormBase.cs` . Thanks of ur response.

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer, click on the Form with your right hand and press **F7** with your left. The form now opens in Code View every time.

Comment: What that means? You indirectly open Form in Code View(F7) ..!